# Is it possible to have a variable that's only calculated whenever a filter is applied?

Tags: dax, ssas, cube

I'm trying to optimize a measure, and after analyzing it I found that the problem comes from the fact that part of it is calculated on every row when it only needs to be calculated once when a certain filter is applied.

Here's the measure :

```
Effectif :=
VAR LastPeriod =
    MAX ( 'Time'[Period] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Sales'[ClientID] ),
        FILTER (
            Sales,
            OR (
                LastPeriod - Sales[ClientLastOrder] < 4,
                LastPeriod - Sales[ClientEntry] < 4
            )
        )
    )
```

In this case, LastPeriod will be calculated over and over, whereas we only need it to be calculated once when a filter is applied on Time.

Is there any way to store this information somewhere so that it doesn't have to make superfluous calculations ?

Comment: Variables are calculated only once. That's why we use them in DAX codes. That's why It is considered a best practice to use variables in your code. Keeping something that doesn't change in a variable is the right method.

Comment: @OzanSen thanks for your response. Do you mean that they're calculated only once within the measure or in the calculation of the measure over multiple lines ? Because the problematic aspect of that calculation is that if the measure is calculated over 100 row contexts, I believe that max() will be calculated 100 times, even if it's inside the variable.

Comment: Its scope is VAR-RETURN block within a statement. In your code, It is calculated once; because It belongs to the end of the RETURN clause. Did you run your code ?  What is the query time, SE,FE ratios ? and also query plan ?

Comment: Your Code is slow. I think there are 2 reasons : DISTINCTCOUNT usage is a problematic issue in terms of performance. As a second reason, You iterate a full table in FILTER() function instead of just the columns you need. If sales table is more than >1 billion, problems starts to mount up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 2 Codes, and let me know If one or both of them are any faster. Instead of iterating (or scanning ) a full table, you only iterate the columns you need in a filter argument. Like this:

Version-1

```
Effectif :=
VAR LastPeriod =
    MAX ( 'Time'[Period] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Sales'[ClientID] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Sales[ClientLastOrder], Sales[ClientEntry] ),
            OR (
                LastPeriod - Sales[ClientLastOrder] < 4,
                LastPeriod - Sales[ClientEntry] < 4
            )
        )
    )
```

Version-2

```
Effectif :=
VAR LastPeriod =
    MAX ( 'Time'[Period] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Sales'[ClientID] ),
        CALCULATETABLE (
            SUMMARIZE ( Sales, Sales[ClientLastOrder], Sales[ClientEntry] ),
            OR (
                LastPeriod - Sales[ClientLastOrder] < 4,
                LastPeriod - Sales[ClientEntry] < 4
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to be confident without any data sample, but I guess that this formula of LastPeriod calculating may help you:

```
VAR LastPeriod =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX ( 'Time'[Period] ),
        ALL('Sales')
    )
```

Also you may check such function as ALLSELECTED(). It may fit you more.

Comment: What if we add an additional filter to that: Your_Measure =
VAR LastPeriod =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Time'[Period] ), ALL ( 'Sales' ), VALUES ( 'Time'[Period] ) )
RETURN
    LastPeriod

Comment: @OzanSen, it would be an excess, because the result will be the same as for MAX ( Calendar'[Date] ): you expand your data using ALL(), but at the same time cut it with VALUES() to original size. At least, it is actual for my dummy data set.

Comment: @Darkitechtor thanks for your answer. However I'm not sure it optimizes it because we'd still be making this max(period) calculation at every iteration of the Effectif measure on the data rows (as in, if we have 1000 rows, we'd calculate the max 1000 times, whereas we only need that information once).